# find closest rows between dataframes with positive timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two `dataframes` each with a `datetime` column:

```
df_long=
     mytime_long
0    00:00:01 1/10/2013
1    00:00:05 1/10/2013
2    00:00:55 1/10/2013

df_short=
     mytime_short
0    00:00:02 1/10/2013
1    00:00:03 1/10/2013
2    00:00:06 1/10/2013
```

The timestamps are unique and can be assumed sorted in each of the two dataframes.

I would like to create a new dataframe that contains the nearest (index,`mytime_long`) **after or at the same time** value in `mytime_short` (hence with a non-negative timedelta)

```
ex.
0  (0, 00:00:02 1/10/2013)
1  (2, 00:00:06 1/10/2013)
2  (np.nan,np.nat)
```

Comment: are the timestamps unique in each dataframe, and do you want to match rows where the delta = 0?

Comment: I hope I have clarified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write a function to get the closest index & timestamp in df_short given a timestamp

```
def get_closest(n):
    mask = df_short.mytime_short >= n
    ids = np.where(mask)[0]
    if ids.size > 0:
        return ids[0], df_short.mytime_short[ids[0]]
    else:
        return np.nan, np.nan
```

apply this function over `df_long.mytime_long`, to get a new data frame with the index & timestamp values in a tuple

```
df = df_long.mytime_long.apply(get_closest)
df
# output:
0    (0, 2013-01-10 00:00:02)
1    (2, 2013-01-10 00:00:06)
2                  (nan, nan)
```

---

ilia timofeev's answer reminded me of this [`pandas.merge_asof` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) which is perfect for this type of join

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_long, 
              df_short.reset_index(), 
              left_on='mytime_long', 
              right_on='mytime_short', 
              direction='forward')[['index', 'mytime_short']]
df
# output:
   index        mytime_short
0    0.0 2013-01-10 00:00:02
1    2.0 2013-01-10 00:00:06
2    NaN                 NaT
```

Comment: maybe is worth making m explict?

Comment: @ErroriSalvo, thanks, that was a typo when I copied my answer from the text editor to SO

Comment: @iliatimofeev, I added another solution, could you run the benchmark on that as well. thanks.

Comment: @HaleemurAli it's great :) 10ms on the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit ugly, but effective way to solve task. Idea is to join them on timestamp and select first "short" after "long" if any.

```
#recreate data 
df_long = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.to_datetime( ['00:00:01 1/10/2013','00:00:05 1/10/2013','00:00:55 1/10/2013']),
    index = [0,1,2],columns = ['mytime_long'])

df_short = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.to_datetime( ['00:00:02 1/10/2013','00:00:03 1/10/2013','00:00:06 1/10/2013']),
    index = [0,1,2],columns = ['mytime_short'])

#join by time, preserving ids
df_all = df_short.assign(inx_s=df_short.index).set_index('mytime_short').join( 
    df_long.assign(inx_l=df_long.index).set_index('mytime_long'),how='outer')
#mark all "short" rows with nearest "long" id
df_all['inx_l'] = df_all.inx_l.ffill().fillna(-1)

#select "short" rows 
df_short_candidate = df_all[~df_all.inx_s.isnull()].astype(int)
df_short_candidate['mytime_short'] = df_short_candidate.index

#select get minimal "short" time in "long" group,
#join back with long to recover empty intersection
df_res = df_long.join(df_short_candidate.groupby('inx_l').first())

print (df_res)
```

Out:

```
          mytime_long  inx_s        mytime_short
0 2013-01-10 00:00:01    0.0 2013-01-10 00:00:02
1 2013-01-10 00:00:05    2.0 2013-01-10 00:00:06
2 2013-01-10 00:00:55    NaN                 NaT
```

---

Performance comparison on sample of 100000 elements:

- **186 ms** to execute this implementation.
- **1min 3s** to execute `df_long.mytime_long.apply(get_closest)`

---

**UPD:** but the winner is @Haleemur Ali's `pd.merge_asof` with **10ms**

Comment: nice.any comment with respect to efficiency in comparison with the answer from @Halemuur Ali?

Comment: I've run test's. :) see results in the answer.  General performance guideline -avoid `apply` on rows.

Comment: You can add extra 5% performance by removing sorting in grouping `groupby('inx_l',sort=False)` . But in fact this algorithm has complexity  _O(n +log(n))_, apply version _O(n*log(n))_ .

Comment: I appreciate your honesty. thanks for running the benchmark